# Subscript out of range when copying charts from excel to word

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

Hi i'm facing a subscript out of range error when I tried to copy a chart from excel sheet to word document. I checked the worksheet name it seems to be fine. I tried changing to ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsname) but i received an application define type error. How do I go about resolving this issue.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
   .ChartObjects(1).Activate
   ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
End With
```

The name of the worksheet I'm trying to reference

[image]

Comment: `.ChartObjects(1).ChartArea.Copy` doesn't work?

Comment: as in the error is at with ThisWorkbook.worksheets(wsName)

Comment: Subscript our of range means that sheet wsName does not exist in the workbook that runs VBA. You are using either a wrong name, or a wrong workbook (if you have multiple workbooks open).

Comment: hi it couldn't be the wrong workbook since I'm using thisworkbook, it couldn't be the worksheet name since wsName is inlet Filter, if it helps, the worksheet I'm trying to reference is a chart sheet

Comment: using `thisworkbook` does not guarantee anything... Excel is no longer an MDI document manager, so you need to qualify your worksheets with objects

Comment: "Excel is no longer an MDI document manager" I believe that only affects excel 2013 and above. I'm currently using excel 2007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally figured out what's the problem.

Since I'm referencing a chartsheet and not a worksheet, I have to use .Charts instead of .Worksheets. In addition since it is a chartsheet, the chartsheet itself is a chart object, hence .ChartObjects(1) is not required, only .ChartArea.Copy

Correct Code:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Charts(wsName)
  .ChartArea.Copy
End With
```